# How fast do you have to be traveling in order to travel one light year in one year due to relativistic effects?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, observers, inertial-frames

My apologies if my understanding is incorrect, but I believe that as you approach relativistic speeds you experience time dilation as compared to an outside observer.

So taking into account this effect how fast do you have to be travelling in order to reach an object one light year away in one year (subjective time of the traveller). How much normal time would have passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to travel at $v=\sqrt{0.5}c=0.707c$. To see this, notice that because of lenght contraction the traveler will see shorter distance:

$L=L_0 \sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}$       (1)

where $L_0$ is one year light. If you travel for a year $t_y$, then $L=v*t_y=(v/c)ct_y=L_0(v/c)$.

Replacing that in (1) results in $v/c=\sqrt{0.5}$

UPDATE: the time at earth will be $t$, where $t'$ is one year:

$t'=t/\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}=1.84$ years

Comment: Are you sure your math is right? How are you accounting for the time dilation in the frame of reference of the traveler?

Comment: @Floris the traveler travels one year in its own reference frame, that is what I undesrtood the op asked

Comment: I think the result is $v^2/c^2 = 1/2$, not $v/c = 1/2$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you are right, I solved it too fast, thanks

Comment: @brucesmitherson so 0.25c? that's cool. How much normal time passes in this situation?

Comment: @Aequitas no, $v=.707c$ (remember it is a squareroot)

Comment: @brucesmitherson oh yeh, *facepalm* haha, I think when I put it into google it did (0.5^1)/2

Comment: @Aequitas 1.84 years, seee updated answer